# Cant find iframe with find_element

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing script in python using selenium.
This code should switch focus to iframe on the webpage.
But instead, I get this error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //iframe[@id="lightbox_iframe_4"]`

here is the code:

```
iframe = browser.find_element("xpath", "//iframe[@id="lightbox_iframe_4"]")
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Please help, how to get the iframe element?

---

Here are all modules:

```
from selenium import *
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Tried adding other modules, changing browser. to driver./webdriver.

Comment: you forgot to put the url

Comment: try with `browser.switch_to.frame("lightbox_iframe_4")`

Comment: @soundwave Now I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="https://www.example.com/url"]

Comment: assuming that the locator is correct and the iframe isn't nested inside another frame, you might just need a webdriverwait.  Use webdriverwait with expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(int)

Comment: @devinoff could you please share the url of the page?

Comment: I don’t need help no more. I couldn’t find the answer, so I just opened the link iFrame in new tab and switched to it